# Is there a difference in intended meaning between .s (lower-case) and .S (upper-case) assembly files?

Tags: gcc, assembly, c-preprocessor

I have noticed that some libraries ship with assembly files using a `.s` extension, and others ship assembly files with a `.S` extension. GCC seems to handle these differently.

Is there any intended meaning behind these two different extensions?

Comment: Yes, capital `.S` is intended to be run through the C preprocessor, and gcc does that. See the [list in the gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html).

Comment: Some people recommend using `.S` for hand-written asm source, whether or not you take advantage of the C preprocessor.  One advantage is that `gcc -S foo.c` will never clobber `foo.S`, but it will silently overwrite `foo.s`.  (Note that `.asm` is appropriate for NASM source files, or for other assemblers other than GAS).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that `.S` (uppercase) files are first run through the C preprocessor and afterwards through the assembler, while `.s` (lowercase) files do not contain any preprocessor directives and are fed directly to the assembler.

Comment: There is no mandate for `.s` files not to contain preprocessor directives.  It's just that the preprocessor doesn't run, so if preprocessor directives are present, the assembler tries to interprete them, likely without much success.

Comment: @fuz Well, if you wish for a successful translation, `.s` files better not have any preprocessor directives in them. That was my point.

Comment: Some times, you want to put things into your assembly files that look like preprocessor directives but actually aren't, such as `#APP` marks or line marks.  The preprocessor would gobble these up and complain.

Comment: @fuz: CPP doesn't complain about `#APP` / `#NOAPP`.  They make it through to the assembler, which (these days) just ignores them as comments.  You'd only have a problem if your `#`-comment started with `#if blah blah` or `#define` or other CPP directive.