# How do I go about creating a GAS AT&T format main assembly program that uses the syscall instruction to print "Hello World"?

Tags: linux, assembly, gcc, att, gnu-assembler

I'm on a Linux x86_64 system and my goal is to create an assembly program inside the classic main function. I've tried this and it works fine :

```
.code64
.section .rodata
msg: .ascii "Hello, World!\n"
.set msglen, (. - msg)

.section .text 
.global _start
_start:
  mov $1, %rax
  mov $1, %rdi 
  lea msg, %rsi 
  mov $msglen, %rdx
  syscall

  mov $60, %rax
  mov $0, %rdi 
  syscall
```

I compiled this with "as -o hello.o -s hello.s" and then linked with "ld -o hello hello.o"

However I want my program to be inside the main function and be compiled and linked with respectively "as main.s (... options ) -o main.o" and "gcc main.o (...options) -o main".
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Change `_start` to `main`, and use `lea msg(%rip), %rsi` so your code isn't using any 32-bit absolute addresses (and is position-independent)

- *[How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register)*
- *[32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux)*

---

You can also replace the exit system-call with a `ret`.  Since you didn't need to make any library function calls or move the stack pointer for any other reason, it's still pointing at the return address.

You should also remove `.code64`.  That's already the default state when assembling into a 64-bit ELF object file.  The only time it makes a difference is with `gcc -m32` (`as --32`) when you'd rather have the assembler tell you that RAX isn't a register instead of assembling 64-bit machine code into a 32-bit object file to eventually get decoded differently when the CPU runs it in 32-bit mode.  Only use mode overrides like `.code32` or `.code64` when you're mixing bitness within the same program, such as for a kernel, or doing weird hacky stuff like a far-jump (AT&T `ljmp`) to a different mode in user-space.

---

If you're using `gcc`, you don't need to assemble separately, you can have it run the assembler for you like `gcc -c main.S` and then link, or just `gcc main.S` to assemble + link, exactly like how `gcc hello.c` will compile + assemble + link.

Comment: Just read this and I wonder why you wrote `main.S` with a capital 'S' (consistently twice). The OP wasn't capitalizing on `hello.s`. Is it just a habit or does it have some other meaning?

Comment: @SepRoland: hand-written asm source files are normally called `.S` (or `.asm` for non-Unix assemblers like NASM).  `gcc foo.S` will run the file through the C preprocessor, but `gcc foo.s` won't (*[Is there a difference in intended meaning between .s (lower-case) and .S (upper-case) assembly files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50882345)*).  So you can `#include <sys/syscall.h>` and use `mov $SYS_write, %eax` instead of hard-coding magic constants like `mov $1, %eax`.  The other advantage is that `gcc -S main.c` will silently overwrite `main.s`, but not `main.S`.

Comment: @SepRoland: See also *[Assembly Files: Difference between .a .s .asm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34098596)* / *[What are .S files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10285410)* although none of those answers are authoritative or definitive, other than the fact that `.S` is mandatory if you use preprocessor directives.  I prefer `.S` even if you don't, to signify that it's hand-written and a true source file, not a compiler temporary.

Comment: @Peter Cordes. Thank you for the suggestions, I've posted a new updated question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77972648/hello-world-x86-64-is-this-100-correct

Comment: @Peter Cordes ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77980526/gnu-c-library-assembly-syscall-source-files-location?noredirect=1#comment137476985_77980526